# Is there a way to visualize GradientBoosting or XGboost after modeling

Tags: python, visualization, gradient, xgboost, boosting

Is there a way to visualize GradientBoosting or XGboost after modeling in python? Like any plots.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to visualize Xgboost after model

```
model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X, y)
plot_tree(model)
plt.show()
```

package `from xgboost import XGBClassifier`